# haskellのdoctestで日本語をテストする方法

Tags: haskell

haskellのdoctestで日本語をテストする方法を知りたいです

```haskell
module Main where    
-- | 日本語表示
-- >>> hoge
-- "日本語"
hoge :: String
hoge = "日本語"

main :: IO ()
main = print hoge
```

上記内容をテストすると

> expected: "日本語"
>   but got: "\26085\26412\35486"
>   Examples: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 1

となってしまいます

ファイルやシステムの文字コードはUTF8に統一しています
doctest version 0.9.11.1

解決方法がありましたら、教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 8):

対処療法的ではありますが、 **putStr** を使うのはどうでしょうか。
[doctest の Usage](https://github.com/sol/doctest/tree/0.9.11.1#usage) を見る限り、ghci で入力したように動作するようですので。

例:

```haskell
-- | 日本語表示
-- >>> putStr hoge
-- 日本語
hoge :: String
hoge = "日本語"
```